# Seeking equivalent to ArcMap Feature to Polygon tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Is there a method, combination of tools or a tool which can achieve the same as the [Feature to Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003n000000) tool of ArcMap?

I want to get the same result just like I would use that tool.

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative to using ArcGIS for Desktop to do this, or just a means to do this with a Basic level license of ArcGIS for Desktop?  I recommend that you edit this important detail into your Question.  Also, this tool can be used in several ways, does your desired solution need to meet all of those requirements or just (a) particular one(s)?  And what version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an Advanced license then [ET GeoWizards](http://www.ian-ko.com/downloads/downloads.htm) is the next best thing to use. The conversion tools are free

Comment: And will I find Feature to Polygon in there? If not, what is the name of the alternative?

Comment: Yes Conversion tools include: 
    Polygon To Polyline
    Polygon To Point
    Polyline To Point
    Polyline To Polygon
    Point To Polyline
    Polyline To Polygon
    Multipoint To Point
    Shape Z (M) To Shape
    Polygon Z (M) To Point
    Polyline Z (M) To Point
    Point Z (M) To Point
    Point To Polygon Z (M)
    Point To Polyline Z (M)
    Point To Point Z (M)
    Point To Multipoint
    Shape To ShapeZ
    Polyline To Multipoint
    Multipoint To Polyline

Comment: The best would be if we don't need to purchase another thing again, because ArcGIS was too expensive.

Comment: Its free of charge

Comment: Geog: ET GeoWizards is not free.

Comment: The conversion functions are free

Comment: And which one is the alternative of Feature to Polygon? I'm not a GIS worker, so I don't really know.

Comment: Polyline to polygon

Comment: Your answer seems to be okay, but only the GIS workers can test that. If this will be good for them, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org) - free! Somewhere in the toolbox there's be a tool for it - just do a search for "polygon" - I think it's called "line to polygon".

QGIS has a very large number of advanced tools that are only available in the super-expensive ArcGIS (or with addons). In fact it's useful to keep around even if you have an ArcGIS Advanced license.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Spatial Ecology tools as well at http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/tooldesc.php

Comment: Looking at their web-page I'd be surprised if they work with ArcGIS 10.x (if that's what the poster is using).