# Looking for QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS "Feature to Polygon" tool

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, polygon-creation, polygonize

I am looking for a tool (a workflow) in QGIS that does exactly the same as the ["Feature To Polygon"](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-polygon.htm) in ArcGIS available with the *Advanced license*.

[image: feature-to-polygon]

I have seen a related question [Seeking equivalent to ArcMap Feature to Polygon tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81567/is-there-equivalent-to-arcgis-feature-to-polygon-tool-available) but the option for QGIS is not explicit enough.

Comment: You know, Taras, the answer shouldn't be directly in the question ;-) I have no idea, how to better achieve this.

Comment: @Erik, I know what you are talking about, these are just my attempts :) If I don't find a better solution, maybe I will put them as an answer.

Comment: The one thing I wish the QGIS tools had was a tolerance setting.

Comment: Is it possible to do **Case 3** under QGIS ? One layer can't be (once loaded) multi-geometry type ? So for me it's only **Case 1** and **Case 2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am familiar with QGIS I do not think that there is a single equivalent tool, rather a single tool for each specific case, is not it?

**Case 1.** Line input ➔ ["Polygonize"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#polygonize)

*Output:*
[image: case_1]

**Case 2.** Polygon input ➔ SAGA's ["Polygon Self-Intersection"](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.1.4/shapes_polygons_12.html) tool

*Output:*
[image: case_2]

**Case 3.** Line and Polygon inputs ➔ (1) ["Polygons to lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#polygons-to-lines) (2) ["Merge vector layers"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#merge-vector-layers) (3) ["Polygonize"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#polygonize)

*Input:*
[image: input]

*Output:*
[image: output]